# Limits are local

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following proposition from Terence Tao's book. Let X be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let E be a subset of X, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of E.

let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let L be a real number. Let $\delta$ > 0. Then we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0; x \in E} f(x) = L$$ iff 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0; x \in E \cap (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} \ f(x) = L$$

Attempt:

Given $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $\delta^{\prime}$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta^{\prime} \implies$ $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

If $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \cap (x_0 - \delta^{\prime}, x_0 + \delta^{\prime}) = \emptyset$. Then the statement:

$|x - x_0| < \delta^{\prime}$ such that $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \implies$ $|f(x) - f(x_0) < \epsilon$ is vacuously true.

Otherwise we have elements in common and the $\epsilon-\delta^{\prime}$ condition is satisfied.

Conversely, Given $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $\delta^{\prime}$ such that:

$|x - x_0| < \delta^{\prime}$ such that $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \subset E \implies$ $|f(x) - f(x_0) < \epsilon$. But then we have that:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0; x \in E} f(x) = L$$

Comment: That intersection is never empty.

Comment: What is an adherent point? A limit point?

Comment: @Rick yeah limit point. It is more general though as it accepts also isolated points.

Comment: What does "otherwise we have elements in common" mean?